# Leapmotion with javascript

Tags: javascript, leap-motion

I am Learning leap motion programmes with javascript. i have few doubts regarding it

1. Is there any way to write gesture for particular finger means circle gesture for index finger and swipe gesture for middle finger??
2. I am trying to draw pot structure as user moves his hand in pot's shape. i have done it but i want to do it in 3d how can i do that in better way. example will be very helpfull.
3. how can we control mouse with leap motion.

Sample codes will help better.

Comment: These are very broad questions, and in particular 3 is a general one and not really Javascript. Have a look at the other questions here and the examples on Leap's website.

Answer (score 1):

1. Given the current version of the tracking, identifying individual fingers as an "index finger" or "pinky finger" is not possible. The API simply gives you a list of currently detected fingers in an "arbitrary order" as [seen in the documentation](http://js.leapmotion.com/api/v0.3.0/docs#leap-hand). If you look at the [announced plans for the future](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/11/20/leap-motion-unveils-freeform-3d-sculpting-app-previews-new-gesture-tracking-software/#!upSvY), you can see more robust hand modeling that may support what you're attempting to do at some point.
2. Not sure what you mean here. If you're looking to reveal a 3D model of a pot when the user moves their hands in a particular manner, I'd look at the Three.js library which can integrate easily with a LeapMotion application.
3. I don't believe you could control the mouse via LeapMotion from a browser application with JavaScript. You'd probably need to write OS specific native applications to accomplish this.